# How to restore OS X Mavericks theme to default

Tags: macos, themes

I've installed a theme, but I don't like it. How can I revert back to default?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sorry to be the bearer of bad news, but OS X doesn't have a theming system, so themes generally work by replacing the system files that contain the GUI graphics (icons and such).

So, follow the instructions that came with your theme on how to uninstall your theme and restore your original system files. If your theme came with no such instructions, you could either restore your system to a backup from before you installed the theme, or re-install OS X in-place (that is, don't wipe the drive, just reinstall your current version of OS X over your current install, so that any files that the "theme" replaced or deleted get reinstalled.

If you don't want to restore your entire system, you could possibly inspect the theme installer to learn what files it installs where, and then just look for those particular files in your backups from before you installed the theme, and restore just those files.

Which ever approach you take, I recommend you first make sure you have a recent full system back, and TEST YOUR BACKUP before proceeding.